# Model Class definiton using redux-orm and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-orm

I'm using **redux-orm** with JS and all is working ok, but I having problems translating my code from JS to **TypeScript**.

I already implemented the method **render()** in my Folder Model Class, but the TS transpiler says:

`Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Folder'`

**How can I indicate TypeScript that the *name* property exists in Folder instances?**

```js
interface IFolder{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    parent: any;
}

export class Folder extends Model<ModelFields, IFolder>{

    static get modelName() {
        return 'Folder';
    }

    get render(){
        return (<p>{this.name}</p>)
    }

    static get fields() {
        return {
            id: attr(),
            name: attr(),
            parent: fk('Folder', 'children')
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat all `IFolder` in `class Folder`

```
export class Folder extends Model<ModelFields, IFolder> implements IFolder {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    parent: any;
...
```

or use this trick to not repeat code:

```
class IFolder extends Model<ModelFields, IFolder> {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    parent: any;
}

export class Folder extends IFolder {
```

Comment: Thanks @aquz I already tried that solution but when I make that I get this error when I want to create an instance of Folder using this line that works ok in using JS:

**Folder.create(sf)**



`index.js:1375 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at SessionBoundModel.update (Model.js:538)
    at SessionBoundModel.set (Model.js:518)
    at SessionBoundModel.set [as id] (descriptors.js:25)
    at new Folder (index.tsx:107)`

Answer (score 0):

Babel transpilation output introduces additional property descriptors in **Model** prototype chain, which interfere with descriptors installed by **redux-orm** during schema registration. This is the root cause for `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

`@types/redux-orm` for `redux-orm:0.13` work a bit differently.

The source provided is missing the `ModelFields`, so I'll skip these and assume that the expected fields include:

- *id* - attribute
- *name*  - attribute
- *parent* - self-referencing foreign key

Example:

```
interface FolderFields {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  parent: Folder
  children: QuerySet<Folder>
}

export class Folder extends Model<typeof Folder, FolderFields> {
    static modelName = 'Folder' as const;
    static fields = {
        id: attr(),
        name: attr(),
        parent: fk('Folder', 'children')
    }
}
```

Types for redux-orm 0.14 will most likely leverage declaration merging to allow for cleaner `Model` definitions.